# array_combine results only one result

Tags: php, arrays, array-combine

I am using the following code to get two arrays into one json result. But getting only the first index as result. Is there any error in the code or anybody can suggest an alternate method to get the same result.

```
$array1 = $_POST['array1'];
$array2 = $_POST['array2'];

$jsonArray = array();
foreach (array_combine( $array1, $array2 ) as $name => $value) {
    $jsonArray[] = array('name' => $name, 'value' => $value);
}

echo $json = json_encode($jsonArray);

$_POST['array1'] = array(4) {
[0]=>
string(3) "day1"
[1]=>
string(3) "day2"
[2]=>
string(3) "day3"
[3]=>
string(3) "day4"
}

$_POST['array2'] = array(4) {
[0]=>
string(3) "item1"
[1]=>
string(3) "item2"
[2]=>
string(3) "item3"
[3]=>
string(3) "item4"
}
```

Expected result should be like

```
[{"name":"day1","value":"item1"},{"name":"day2","value":"item2"},{"name":"day3","value":"item3"}]
```

Comment: where is your result? expected output, please?

Comment: The output you've provided correctly echo's out `[{"name":"size","value":"L"},{"name":"color","value":"Black"}]` (Before you edited it). Check your `$_POST` array and make sure it's the expected values.

Comment: It looks like you are expecting a result that would come from array_merge. You might want to check the documentation of array_combine at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

Comment: What's the result that you expect. Can you mock it up so that we get a visual of what you expect?

Comment: Your code works fine https://3v4l.org/J6XXY

Comment: Another way to combine your array without using `array_combine` https://3v4l.org/fMILF

Answer (score 0):

**Try this,**

```
$arr1 = array('0' => 'day1', '1' => 'day2', '2' => 'day3', '3' => 'day4');
echo'<pre>';print_r($arr1);
$arr2 = array('0' => 'item1','1' =>  'item2','2' =>  'item3','3' =>  'item4');
echo'<pre>';print_r($arr2);
echo'<pre>';print_r(array_combine($arr1, $arr2));
 $newArray = array();
  foreach(array_combine($arr1, $arr2) as $key => $value){
      array_push($newArray, array('name'=> $key,'value'=>$value));
  }
echo'<pre>';print_r($newArray);
echo json_encode($newArray);die;
```